# How to normalize the schema to BCNF

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, bcnf

I am having some issues with normalization. I have a schema **REPAYMENT** which looks like this: [image]

Now, from what I've gathered the functional dependencies that hold in the schema is

{borrower_id} --> {name, address, request_date, loan_amount}

{request_date} --> {repayment_date, loan_amount}

{loan_amount] --> {repayment_amount}

(correct me if I'm wrong?)

I'm supposed to normalise the schema to BCNF, but I'm a bit confused. Is the candidate key request_date and borrower_id?

It can be used to register information on the re- payments on micro loans. A borrower, his name and address, are identified with an unique borrower_id. Borrowers can have multiple loans at the same time, but each of those loans ( specified by loan_amount, repayment_date and repayment_amount) have a different re- quest date. Thus a loan can be identified with the borrower ID and the request date of the loan. The borrower can repay multiple (different) loans on the same date, but each loan can only be repaid once (on one date with one amount). There is a system which for each request date and amount of a loan determines the repayment date and amount to be repaid. The loan amount requested and the repaid amount are not the same since there is an interest rate that applies.

Comment: First you need to be sure what the dependencies are. This looks like homework. Are the dependencies given to you in the question or are you expected to guess based on the names of the attributes?

Comment: As said in the previous comment, without the certainty about the functional dependencies it is impossible to transform a relation schema in a normal form. And the functional dependencies can be given only by understanding the meaning of the data represented. For instance from your dependencies, we can derive that the request date determines the load amount. How this is possibile? The amount of the loan depends on the date in which it has been required? Finally note that, given the functional dependencies specified in the question, the *only* possible candidate key is borrower_id.

Comment: I've added the details. And its not homework but an old exam my course had last year

Comment: What reference text are you to use? You ask about FDs--what is the *definition* you are using? You want to determine the CKs--what is the *definition* you are using? What is your justification for *every pair of attribute subsets* that X->Y does or does not hold? Why do you say "the CK" instead of "the set of CKs"? Do you understand that every subset determines itself? What exactly do you see as the process to follow? PS [Please use text, not images/links, for text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The FD `request_date->loan_amount` seems unlikely, given your explanatory comments. So does `borrower_id->request_date` and `borrower_id->loan_amount`. More likely `borrower_id->name, address`, and `borrower_id, request_date->repayment_date, loan_amount`.

Comment: @In6ify Your functional dependencies is not consistent with the information you provided.

Comment: @In6ify If you compute the candidate key using the functional dependencies you provided then its borrower_id, however as you said there are multiple loans allowed for the same person.

Comment: @In6ify My answer assumes that only 1 loan is allowed or the same person gets a different borrower_id for different loans.

Comment: @SumeetSingh If the question is contradictory and/or unclear, ask for clarification, don't guess at an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of candidate key:

> In the relational model of databases, a candidate key of a relation is
>   a minimal superkey for that relation; that is, a set of attributes
>   such that:
>
> 1. The relation does not have two distinct tuples (i.e. rows or records in common database language) with the same values for these
>      attributes (which means that the set of attributes is a superkey)
> 2. There is no proper subset of these attributes for which (1) holds (which means that the set is minimal).

Now your question :

> Is the candidate key request_date and borrower_id?

It is a superkey, but not minimal one. Here's how we compute the candidate key.

Which attribute occurs only on the left side, considering all the F . D's ?

ITS  *borrower_id*.This means that it must be a part of every key of this given schema. Now let us compute its closure.

Because of *{borrower_id} --> {name, address, request_date, loan_amount}*:

closure(borrower_id) = borrower_id, name, address, request_date, loan_amount.

Because of *{request_date} --> {repayment_date, loan_amount}* and closure(borrower_id) has *request_date*, this means

closure(borrower_id) = borrower_id, name, address, request_date, loan_amount, repayment_date

And finally because of *{loan_amount] --> {repayment_amount}* and closure(borrower_id) has *loan_amount*, this means

closure(borrower_id) = borrower_id, name, address, request_date, loan_amount, repayment_date, repayment_amount

Because closure of *borrower_id* contains all the attributes, *borrower_id* is a key and since it is minimal, it is indeed the **candidate key** and the only one.

Now let us decompose the schema into **BCNF**. The algorithm is:

> Given a schema R.
>
> 1. Compute keys for R.
> 2. Repeat until all relations are in BCNF.
>
>    - Pick any R' having a F.D `A --> B` that violates BCNF.
>    - Decompose R' into R1(A,B) and R2(A,Rest of attributes).
>    - Compute  F.D's for R1 and R2.
>    - Compute keys for R1 and R2.

Since *{request_date} --> {repayment_date, loan_amount}* and *request_date* is not a key, it violates BCNF so we split schema into two relations:

1. R1(request_date,repayment_date,loan_amount)
2. R2(borrower_id,name,address,request_date,repayment_amount)

Clearly R1 is in BCNF. But R2 is **NOT** in BCNF , because we missed the following F.D. which is:

```
address --> name
```

and we know address is not the key, so we split the R2 further as:

1. R3(borrower_id,address,request_date,repayment_amount)
2. R4(address,name)

Now, clearly both R3 and R4 are in BCNF. Had we not split the R2 further, we end up storing the same combination of address and name for every loan the person takes, which is redundancy.